# Using "sed" to delete a line containing something and the next line

Tags: regex, sed

Assume a file with the following contents:

```
good
good bad
next of baaaad
good
```

I want to use `sed` to delete lines which contain "bad" and the next line of these lines. In above example I want to delete line 2 and line 3.

How can I do that?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
ebra@him:/tmp$ cat iio | sed -e "s/\n.*bad.*\n.*//"
good
good bad
next of baaaad
good
```

Comment: Note that sed is *strictly* line-oriented, so  the pattern space will *never* contain a newline (unless you use one of the commands that explicitly adds one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sed`:

```
sed '/bad/{N;d}'  Input_file
```

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '/bad/{getline;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Isn't there any way using `sed`?

Comment: @Abraham, please see my update above and let me know then?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed, you can specify address ranges with matches and a number of lines following the match:

```
$ sed '/bad/,+1d' infile
good
good
```

Answer (score 3):

give this one-liner a try:

```
sed '/bad/{N;d}' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  cat f
1good
2good bad
3good --
4good
5bad
6good--
7good

kent$  sed '/bad/{N;d}' f
1good
4good
7good
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e '/bad/{N;d;}'
```

On a line that matches `/bad/`, append the next line to pattern space, then delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another `sed` command that works with `gnu sed`:

```
sed '/bad/,+1 d' file
```

```
good
good
```

This `sed` allows you to remove any number of lines after matching a pattern e.g. to delete 2 lines after match:

```
sed '/bad/,+2 d' file
```